# Dynamic graph with matplotlib and psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, matplotlib, flask, psycopg2

I'm making a Flask web app that pulls data from a postgresql database. I'm using psycopg2 to manage the connection with the db.

If I want to have a **graph of user activity** (# of users active) **over a period of time** (for example, the last 7 days), how can I represent this dynamically with matplotlib?

My psycopg2 query to get the user count within the past 7 days would look like this (EDITED):

```
timeInterval = 7;

def userCount(conn, cur):
    cur.execute("""SELECT count(DISTINCT(username)) from user_table WHERE tstampz > 
               (current_timestamp - make_interval(days := %s))""", [timeInterval]
    return cur.fetchone()[0]
```

My question is how can I get the result of this query in my matplotlib graph?

Answer (score 0):

First, you want a query which shows the timestamps, otherwise you have no way to graph the time series.  I also have no idea what you're doing with that "make_interval()" function, which isn't required.  So your query should read:

```
    cur.execute("""SELECT tstampz, count(DISTINCT(username)) 
                from user_table 
                WHERE tstampz > 
               (current_timestamp - INTERVAL '7 days')
               GROUP BY tstampz ORDER BY tstampz;""")
```

(BTW, thank you for using timestamps with time zones)

Matplotlib wants you to restructure the data as an array, so you'll want to loop through it and build the arrays:

```
tses = []
ucounts = []
for rec in cur:
  tses.append(rec[0])
  ucounts.append(rec[1])
```

You can then assign these to plots.  Note that this construction assumes that you don't have gaps in your time sequence; if you do, you'll need to take a more sophisticated approach.

```
ax.plot(tses, ucounts, color='blue', label='User Count')
```

You can find more complete examples by [downloading the Jupiter notebook](https://github.com/jberkus/jberkus.github.io/tree/master/ipython_graphs) from my tutorial on matplotlib and Postgres.

Comment: oops, I changed the my code for the purpose of the question and didn't realize it didn't make sense. Fixed it in the original question. Thanks for your comment, I'll try this out!